# Web audio API oscillator onstarted event

Tags: javascript, events, web-audio-api

The *Web Audio API* oscillator allows a script to be alerted when the oscillator stops with `onended`.

How can the script be alerted when it starts?

```js
const ac = new AudioContext()

const osc = ac.createOscillator()
osc.type = 'sawtooth'
osc.connect(ac.destination)

osc.onstarted = () => console.log('ended!') // This doesn't work :'(
osc.onended = () => console.log('ended!') // :)

osc.start(5)
osc.stop(7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ended` event is the only event that an `OscillatorNode` emits. I guess this is because this event is inherited from the `AudioScheduledSourceNode` interface.

Another node which inherits that interface is the `AudioBufferSourceNode`. And for an `AudioBufferSourceNode` it's often not so easy to tell when it actually ends which is why I think the event exists. This could also be the reason why there is no `started` event.

Anyway you can re-build that functionality by using another `AudioScheduledSourceNode`. I would recommend to use a `ConstantSourceNode` since it is the one which is the most lightweight.

```
const constantSourceNode = new ConstantSourceNode(ac);

constantSourceNode.onended = () => {
    console.log('osc started');
};
constantSourceNode.start();
constantSourceNode.stop(5);
```

Please note that the `ended` events are not very accurate. They get triggered on the audio thread and need to travel back to the main thread where they finally get fired when there is some time to do so.